# Strange recursion optimization by java

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow, tail-recursion

I came across some weird results when I was trying to answer this question: [How to improve the performance of the recursive method?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10884217/373151)

But you don't need to read that post. I'll give the relevant context here.
This might seem lengthy but really isn't that complicated if you read through once. I hope it will be interesting for all. For context,

```
syra(n) = { 1 if n=1; 
            n + syra(n/2) if n is even; and 
            n + syra(3n+1) if n is odd
          }
```

and

```
syralen(n) = No. of steps to calculate syra (n)
```

e.g,
`syralen(1)=1`, `syralen(2)=2 since we need to go two steps.` 
`syra(10) = 10 + syra(5) = 15 + syra(16) = 31 + syra(8) = 39 + syra(4) = 43 + syra(2) = 45 + syra(1) = 46`. So syra(10) needed 7 steps. Therefore `syralen(10)=7`

And finally,

```
lengths(n) = syralen(1)+syralen(2)+...+syralen(n)
```

The question poster there is trying to calculate `lengths(n)`

My question is about the recursive solution the Op has posted (which is the second snippet in that question). I'll repost it here:

```
public class SyraLengths{

        int total=1;
        public int syraLength(long n) {
            if (n < 1)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            if (n == 1) {
                int temp=total;
                total=1;
                return temp;
            }
            else if (n % 2 == 0) {
                total++;
                return syraLength(n / 2);
            }
            else {
                total++;
                return syraLength(n * 3 + 1);
            }
        }

        public int lengths(int n){
            if(n<1){
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }
            int total=0;
            for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
                total+=syraLength(i);
            }

            return total;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args){
            System.out.println(new SyraLengths().lengths(5000000));
        }
       }
```

Surely an unusual (and probably not recommended) way of doing it recursively, but it does calculate the right thing, I have verified that. I tried to write a more usual recursive version of the same:

```
public class SyraSlow {

    public long lengths(int n) {
        long total = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
            total += syraLen(i);
        }
        return total;
    }

    private long syraLen(int i) {
        if (i == 1)
            return 1;
        return 1 + ((i % 2 == 0) ? syraLen(i / 2) : syraLen(i * 3 + 1));
    }
```

Now here's the weird part - I tried to test the performance of both the above versions like:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
            long t1=0,t2=0;
            int TEST_VAL=50000;

            t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println(new SyraLengths().lengths(TEST_VAL));
            t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("SyraLengths time taken: " + (t2-t1));

            t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println(new SyraSlow().lengths(TEST_VAL));
            t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("SyraSlow time taken: " + (t2-t1));
        }
```

For `TEST_VAL=50000`, the output is:

```
5075114
SyraLengths time taken: 44
5075114
SyraSlow time taken: 31
```

As expected (I guess) the plain recursion is slightly better. But when I go one step further and use `TEST_VAL=500000`, the output is:

```
62634795
SyraLengths time taken: 378
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at SyraSlow.syraLen(SyraSlow.java:15)
    at SyraSlow.syraLen(SyraSlow.java:15)
    at SyraSlow.syraLen(SyraSlow.java:15)
```

Why is it? What kind of optimization is being done by Java here that the SyraLengths version doesn't hit StackOverflow (It works even at `TEST_VAL=5000000`)? **I even tried using an accumulator-based recursive version just in case my JVM was doing some tail-call optimization:**

```
private long syraLenAcc(int i, long acc) {
        if (i == 1) return acc;
    if(i%2==0) {
        return syraLenAcc(i/2,acc+1);
    }
    return syraLenAcc(i * 3 + 1, acc+1);
    }
```

**But I still got the same result (thus there is no tail-call optimization here).** So then, what's happening here?

P.S: Please edit to a better title if you can think of any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it turns out there is a simple explanation to it:

I am using `long syraLen(int n)` as the method signature. But the value of `n` can actually be much larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. So `syraLen` gets negative inputs and therein lies the problem. If I change it to `long syraLen(long n)`, everything works perfectly! I wish I had also put the `if(n < 1) throw new IllegalArgumentException();` like the original poster. Would have saved me some time.

Answer (score 2):

With the original version, tail recursion optimization was possible (within the JIT).  Dunno whether it actually occurred or not, though.  But it's possible that the original is just slightly more efficient with heap [er, I mean stack] use.  (Or there may be a functional difference that was not obvious on cursory examination.)

Comment: Definitely stack use. Tail recursion prevents massive stack usage if the last statement of a function is a call to itself. In that case the call can be replaced by a jump, roughly speaking. The function is basically wrapped into a kind of loop turning the recursion into iteration. (Don't shout at me, I know that's a bit of over-simplification.)

Comment: But I have tried the second version with an accumulator, if tail call optimization was happening, it should have helped that too

Comment: According to this: http://openjdk.java.net/projects/mlvm/subprojects.html and this: http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6804517 tail-optimization is not there yet. Look at `Tail calls and tail recursion`. Look here also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/105897/639753

Comment: The `?` statement would probably confuse the heck out of the optimizer and cause it to give up on tail recursion optimization.

Comment: @Xeon..exactly.. that is why I am unable to understand this.

Comment: @HotLicks.. I tried with the usual `if...else` too... it didn't help

Comment: @Xeon -- Assuming he's using the Sun/Oracle JVM -- The IBM JVMs had tail recursion optimization 5 years ago.

Comment: @Raze2dust -- If you tried it with if/else and the accumulator you would have had the original version.  Go step by step to see what breaks it.

Comment: I am using Sun's Hotspot JVM.. I am pretty sure it doesn't do tail-call optimization. There should be no difference between the if/else version and snippet 1 really.. I'll post the if/else version too